# How to identify the table name of the folder (from folder view in Alfresco) to join with cmis:document

Tags: java, alfresco, cmis, apache-chemistry

How to write the query joins using CMIS Query language. Given below is the query from the existing code. The folder in the repository is "Client" whereas in the code, the table name for this folder is clientDocument:info. And it joins on cmis:objectId. Appreciate your help in clarifying my question

Example :

```
SELECT
  d.*, g.* 
  FROM
  cmis:document d JOIN clientDocument:info g
  ON
  d.cmis:objectId=g.cmis:objectId
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly:

- aspects "act" like tables
- properties "act" like columns

So if you have a custom aspect containing a property, you're "selecting from or joining" with an aspect (table), and using a property (column) in a where clause.

Comment: Lista, thanks for the answer. Yes. this is what I was looking for. Is there any way to identify the aspects in the Alfresco repository o workbench or r do I  need to query to identify the existing aspects.?

Comment: This should return a JSON response with all the models. http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/dictionary

Comment: I was able to download the JSON and look at the various aspects. It was helpful so I really appreciate your response. Would you be able to point me to a good link that has information on aspects and properties?  How would I know to join on a property, example - Join on ObjectId   "d.cmis:objectId=g.cmis:objectId" from above example

Comment: Also, if I query using the folder name without joining the aspects, it would still fetch the documents from the folder correct, then why join? Example   SELECT d.* FROM cmis:document d WHERE IN_FOLDER(d,?) , this would return the documents under the folder requested. Sorry, it might sound like a silly question but I am trying to understand the relevance of aspects join

Comment: Yes, but to query using a property - you must "join" with it's aspect. Just like in SQL, you can't just use a column, you must first "join" a table containing it.

Comment: Also, realize that joins are only supported by Alfresco to support fetching aspect-based properties. You cannot join between arbitrary types. Check the repository capabilities CMIS call--"capabilityJoin" is set to "none" for Alfresco.